# Grunticon v2.0 inline SVG and sizing

Tags: css, angularjs, svg

I am using [Grunticon](http://www.grunticon.com/) as my SVG workflow. I love the idea and have read a lot of good things about it, but it has been pretty finicky in my Angular project:

- It **doesn't embed** in my HTML when I add the attribute `data-grunticon-embed`. I did set the option `enhanceSVG` to `true` like it says in the [documentation](https://github.com/filamentgroup/grunticon#version-20-is-out---heres-whats-new). This means I can neither style or animate the SVG, which is a huge blocker.
- It's weird that I have to specify element level style - *both* width and height or the SVG won't show up (in pixels too, it doesn't work with rem or em)

I've been reading tons of related Grunticon issues on Github and StackOverflow questions, but no one seems to have the same problem/questions. I'd hugely appreciate if I could get some clarification on these areas.